# Android, what final version is used if multiple libs are using different version of the same dependency

Tags: android, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

In Android app, when different versions of a library have been used in the different libs the app depends on, not clear that how it will affect the final apk's build.
Here is a simplified case to show the question:

There are two 3rd party libs, call it `comm_lib`, `lib_A`. The `Lib_A` has dependency on `comm_Lib:2.0.0`

```
commen_Lib version 2.0.0 has functions:

class Comm {
   fun commFunc() {printlin("in commFunc ver 2.0.0"}
   fun func200{printlin("in func200"}
}

commen_Lib version 3.0.0 has removed func200 and added func300, and changed implementation:

class Comm {
   fun commFunc() {printlin("in commFunc ver 3.0.0"}
   fun func300{printlin("in func300"}
}
```

The Lib_A has dependency comm_Lib:2.0.0.

```
Lib_A using comm_Lib:2.0.0

class LibAclass {
    fun libAFunc() {
        val comm = Comm()
        comm.commFunc() // expect to see "in commFun ver 2.0.0"
        comm.func200()  // func200 is available in comm_Lib ver 2.0.0
    }
}
```

The app has dependency on latest version of `Lib_A` and `comm_Lib:3.0.0`.

```
app using comm_Lib:3.0.0

fun appFunc{
   val comm = Comm()
   comm.commFunc() // want to see "in commFun ver 3.0.0"
   comm.func300(). // available in comm_Lib:3.0.0
   val libA = LibAclass()
   libA.libAFunc() //<=== lib_A was build with comm_Lib:2.0.0, will its calling comm.func200() fail?
   
}
```

I guess in this case the app's dependency graph the comm_Lib should be solved to `comm_Lib:3.0.0`.

In this case what will happen when the app calls `libA.libAFunc()`? will it get the `... not found ...` error on the call to the `comm.func200()`?

In the other way around, if the `Lib_A` was built with `comm_Lib:3.0.0`, and app is using `comm_Lib:2.0.0`

```
Lib_A is using comm_Lib:3.0.0

class LibAclass {
    fun libAFunc() {
        val comm = Comm()
        comm.commFunc() // expect to see "in commFun ver 3.0.0"
        comm.func300(). // func300 is available in comm_Lib ver 3.0.0
    }
}
```

The app has dependency on latest version of `Lib_A` and `comm_Lib:2.0.0`.

```
app using comm_Lib:2.0.0

fun appFunc{
   val comm = Comm()
   comm.commFunc() // want to see "in commFun ver 2.0.0"???
   comm.func200() //<== will it get compile error since the comm_Lib is resolved to 3.0.0
   val libA = LibAclass()
   libA.libAFunc() 
   
}
```